# Inflation in wealth forecast

Tags: simulations, forecasting, inflation, return

I am building a model to simulate people's wealth in the next years.

Say Mr X has a portfolio with an expected return of 3% (annual). From this I can simulate the return of his portfolio in the next 40 years using Geometric Brownian Motion.
I also want him to be able to add inflows/outflows (e.g. Mr X expects a salary of 60K every month and expects to receive 100K as a donation in 5 years).

I now want to adjust all this with inflation.

In my view there are 2 ways to do so:

1. I can adjust the *portfolio return*. So if I consider 2% inflation per year, the real return rate would be 1%.
2. I can adjust the *inflows/outflows*. This approach in my view is a bit more precise, since some cash flows may be impacted by inflation (such as expenses for life goods) and others not (such as fixed interests).

My question: I believe I should adjust inflation doing either 1) or 2) but not both ways simultaneously. Do you agree with this?